# spark datasource IN subquery

Tags: apache-spark, subquery, datasource

I wrote a datasource for spark2.0.3 to load data from another datasource. But when I use In subquery, the filter is null like:

[The in SQL is in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJcDK.png)

But the `=` subquery works like:

[The = SQL is in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpj3g.png)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that we currently do not pushdown `IN` filters into the datasource.

The main issue is that the subquery could potentially contain a lot of values, and that pushing these down itself could become very expensive (large SQL, and the source might not be able to work with these).